# How to Setup Redirection Fallback If Subdomain URL Doesn't Already Have One

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

We have a subdomain (oldblog.oursite.com) and we've set up over 600 redirects to (newblog.oursite.com), however, there are likely some live links to pages on oldblog.oursite.com that we haven't caught and implemented a redirect.

Is there a way to make oldblog.oursite.com redirect any URL that doesn't already have a redirect rule in place to redirect to the index of newblog.oursite.com? Preferably in the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you put it last:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "^/" http://newblog.oursite.com/
```

Please test it. Any problems let me know. Take care that you are testing server generated redirects and not ones cached in your browser. Using 302 redirects during testing can help.